# Date wont display in form after it is sent to Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem my form data is inserted, but it does not display in edit form this is the edit function. The form will add the data it will display it in the database not when you want to display the data, everything displays besides the date.

```
 $scope.updateAddressFunction1 = function (edit_val){
          if (edit_val!=null){
              //pass update values to form and redirect to page 14//editStudent
              //$scope.data = edit_val;
              $rootScope.data = edit_val;
              var dateofbirth = new Date($rootScope.data.dateofbirth);
              var dobd = dateofbirth.getDate();
              var dobm = dateofbirth.getMonth()+1;
              var doby = dateofbirth.getFullYear();
              if (dobd<10){
                dobd = "0" + dobd;
              }
              if (dobm<10){
                dobm = "0" + dobm;
              }
              $rootScope.data.dateofbirth = dateofbirth.toISOString().slice(0,10);
              alert($scope.data.firstname + " | " + $scope.data.surname + " | " + $rootScope.data.dateofbirth);
              $state.go('editStudent', {});
              //alert("Why???");
              // defo something after this function has ran
              //e.preventDefault(); //but there is no e/event
          }
          else{
            console.log("Something went wrong");
          }
      };
```

Comment: Why do you have firebase tag selected?!

Comment: because i am using firebase my form is stored there and i displays all the data besides dates